# Positive continuous function with bounded differential $\int_{0}^{\infty}{f}<\infty$ tends to zero

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, derivatives

Could you help me with this a little?

Let $f$ be a continuous function s.t. $f' \leq C$, $f \geq 0$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty}{f}<\infty$ then $\lim_{t \to \infty}{f(t)}=0$.

What I found so far: 
I used the fundamental thm of calculus to find $f(t)\leq f(0)+C\cdot t$ and that $f(t)$ is bounded for all $t\geq 0$.

Thanks for some hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the contrary: $f$ does not tend to zero at infinity. Then there exists a number $M>0$ and a sequence of points $x_n\to\infty$ such that $f(x_n)\ge M$ for all $n$. By deleting some of the $x_n$ we can assume that $x_{n+1}\ge x_n+M/C$. We have $f(x)\ge f(x_n)-C(x-x_n)$ and so 
$$
 \int_{x_n}^{x_n+M/(2C)}f(x)dx\ge \int_{x_n}^{x_n+M/(2C)}\frac M2 dx\ge\frac{M^2}{4C}.
$$
Thus, we see that $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ diverges, which is a contradiction. QED